# Website specific part stopped to be updated till I clear cache with W3 Total Cache plugin

Tags: wordpress, caching, w3-total-cache

I'm using W3 Toal Cache plugin for WordPress 
And it seems that I have an issue - for some reason, suddenly one section on our site began not to update till we do complete clear cache (It worked perfectly before).
It worked great until these last days.
This is our site's address - http://nocamels.com
And here you can see the problem is where the Newsflash cube in the upper left side of the site.

Is there any option in the settings that we need to turn on/off? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Yuval

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see you're talking about the home page. So, on the "Page Cache" tab of the W3 Total Cache plugin settings, uncheck the "Cache home page" option. This will disable the caching of the home page, and will ensure that your Newsflash widget always shows the most recent posts.